# Verb after gerund verb

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I'm newer to this forum, and I'm learning English. My teacher has taught me that we must use gerund after "enjoy", as in:

> I enjoy swimming.

Now,  if we use a verb after gerund, which verb should I use: base from or infinitive or gerund? for example:

> 1. I enjoy helping you improve your English.

> 2. I enjoy helping you to improve your English.

> 3. I enjoy helping you improving your English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 look fine to me though you should say _your_ English rather than _English._ 3 isn't the way to go about it.

Comment: You don't _always_ need a gerund after 'enjoy'; I enjoy cakes, beer, and company.

Comment: "Help" permits only an infinitival complement (bare or with _to_), but not a gerund-participial one.  So 1. and 2. are correct, but not 3.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I enjoy helping you improve your English.*
>
> [2] *I enjoy helping you to improve your English.*
>
> [3] **I enjoy helping you improving your English*.

"Help" permits only an infinitival complement (bare or with *to*), but not a gerund-participial one.

So [1] and [2] are correct, but not [3].

Answer (score 0):

Both the infinitive form and gerund are ok, i.e. statements 2 and 3. However, there ought to be a "your" before "English".